# Requests made by nginx' proxy_pass fail, but they succeed if done manually

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, wordpress

I am proxying a WP blog that sits behind a second nginx instance (which sends requests to PHP-FPM).

If I make the request from the browser, or from a command line too like HTTPie, the request succeeds. E.g.

```
$ http http://x.y.z.w/test-page/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

However, when using `proxy_pass` the nginx instance on my computer returns 404. Upon checking the WP's blog nginx logs, I see the following:

```
<my-ip> - - [05/Nov/2019:09:53:37 +0000] "GET /test-page/ HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36"
<my-ip> - - [05/Nov/2019:09:53:43 +0000] "GET /test-page/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21317 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36"
```

How is it even possible that everything looks the same but the server first returns 404 and then 200? There must be a difference. I also checked the headers that HTTPie is sending. Nothing out of the ordinary:

```
GET /test-page/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: x.y.z.w
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9
```

Here's the minimal nginx configuration for this test:

```
events {
    worker_connections                 5000;
    multi_accept                       on;
    use                                epoll;
}

http {
    log_format                          timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] ' '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent ' '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" ' '$request_time';

    access_log                           /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined;
    error_log                            /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    resolver                             1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout                     15s;

    index                                index.html;

    upstream front-wp {
        server x.y.z.w:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /wp-content/ {
            proxy_pass http://front-wp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location = /test-page/ {
            proxy_pass http://front-wp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

This issue is really making me crazy.

Comment: One difference is the value of the HTTP Host request header arriving at `x.y.z.w`. Does it work if you use `proxy_set_header Host "x.y.z.w";`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Ah, that's it. Do you know why that is enforced?

Comment: You will need to look at `x.y.z.w`.

Comment: @RichardSmith If you make that an answer I will accept it -- the Host thing I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably that the server at `x.y.z.w` is using name-based virtual hosting, and the two requests are being handled by different virtual hosts.

The URL `http://x.y.z.w/test-page/` sets the Host header value to `x.y.z.w` which is used to select one of the virtual hosts.

The request through the reverse proxy sets the Host header value to `$host` which is used to select another virtual host (possibly the default host when the Host value is unknown).

To confirm this, try:

```
proxy_set_header Host "x.y.z.w";
```

which should make the two requests sufficiently similar to be processed by the same virtual host.

You will need to look at the configuration of the server at `x.y.z.w` if a different behaviour is required.

Comment: Thanks for adding all the details.